# Stop pgfplots from closing a cycle

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I'm trying to draw the graph of a curve in three dimensions.  For some reason, tikz/pgfplots is automatically closing the curve.  I can't figure out how to stop it from doing this.  Here is an example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot3 [
      variable=t,
      domain=-1.5:1.5] ({t},{0},{20-t^2});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What it produces for me is the following:

[image]

For some reason, it has connected the start and end points of the curve.

Comment: For reference, this is described in the `pgfplots` manual, in the section about `\addplot3`. In the manual for version 1.18.1, it's section *4.6.2 The \addplot3 Command: Three Dimensional Coordinate Input*, on page 125. Quote: "The “auto-completion” depends on how you provide your data. • If you use `\addplot3 expression`, `mesh/rows` and `mesh/cols` are computed from the values `samples` and `samples y`. **By default, `\addplot3 expression` always samples a mesh. If you want it to sample a line, set `samples y=1` (or, equivalently, `y domain=0:0`).**"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell PGFPlots to only draw the curve once with `samples y=1`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot3 [variable=t, domain=-1.5:1.5, samples y=1] ({t},{0},{20-t^2});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph]